# Can I update a Model from a jQuery event?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

This is what I would like to (*maybe* - I'm still thinking about doing it all client-side, in jQuery) do, but I don't know if it's possible:

Respond to a user action (selecting a tab or an item from a selection/comboBox) with jQuery, update a (MVC) Model based on what was just selected, and have the html that has Razor code embedded with members of the model immediately update. IOW, if I had code such as:

```
<div>Movie Title</div>
<div>@Model.MovieTitle</div>
<div>Movie Director</div>
<div>@Model.MovieDirector</div>
```

...I would want "MovieTitle" and "MovieDirector" to immediately update.

I don't want to use a Javascript Submit button to fire this off, just the selection of an item or the switching from one tab (navigation ul element) needs to start the ball rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for JavaScript model binding. There are many libraries available, for example [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).

You'll be storing your Razor model in JavaScript by serializing it. Take a look at the various tutorials on the Knockout site, you'll learn a lot even if you decide to go for a different library.